# Expected: reference. Found: double. Error in parameters. What's wrong?

Tags: java, arraylist, parameters, reference, double

I'm working on a code that uses recursion to find the minimum grades I need on my finals. In my MinimumGradeFinder class, I have the following:

```
public ArrayList<double> calculateGrades(int currIndex, double[] setNumbers,
                  double[] volatileNumbers, double targetAvg,
                  int totalCount, int maxGrade) {

  // A bunch of code

  caclulateGrades(currIndex + 1, setNumbers, volatileNumbers,
                  targetAvg, totalCount, maxGrade);
  return minCombos;
  // A private ArrayList<double> intitialized at the top of the class
}
```

And it is throwing the following errors:

```
MinimumGradeFinder.java:13: error: unexpected type
  public ArrayList<double> calculateGrades(int currIndex,
double[] setNumbers, double[] volatileNumbers, double
targetAvg, int totalCount, int maxGrade) {
                   ^
  required: reference
  found:    double
MinimumGradeFinder.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
      caclulateGrades(currIndex + 1, setNumbers,
volatileNumbers, targetAvg, totalCount, maxGrade);
      ^
  symbol:   method caclulateGrades(int,double[],double[],double,int,int)
  location: class MinimumGradeFinder
2 errors

exit status 1
```

What does it mean be "required: reference. found: double"? I don't see anything wrong with the way I call any of the parameters... Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `ArrayList<double>` with `ArrayList<Double>`.

`double` is a primitive type and cannot be used as a type parameter. Its reference counterpart is `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList<double>` should be replaced to `ArrayList<Double>`, in Java, inside the <> always goes a Class or Interface type, not a primitive type (double, int, byte, char, those are primitive types).

I suggest you to use some IDE to work, and more if you are starting, that kind of error will be corrected by suggestion of the IDE itself, you can try with IntelliJ or Eclipse

Comment: Do you think it is worth mentioning explicitly that primitive array types also work, because they are reference types?